# AnyChart 7.12.0 Gantt moving row event does not include index

Tags: api, anychart

I tried using the move example included [here](http://docs.anychart.com/7.12.0/Gantt_Chart/Live_Edit_UI_and_API) and e.itemIndex is undefined. My initial exploration of the e object fails to find an item index attribute. I would like to know the old index of the item being moved and the new index of the item.

```
var tree = anychart.data.tree(getData(), anychart.enums.TreeFillingMethod.AS_TABLE);
    tree.listen(anychart.enums.EventType.TREE_ITEM_MOVE, function(e){
        chart.title.text("The "+e.itemIndex+" item was moved");
    });
```

See my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ax2t5hvt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some trickery is needed, save the index:

```
  chart.listen(anychart.enums.EventType.ROW_MOUSE_DOWN, function(e) {
    var treeDataItem = e.item;
    absoluteSourceIndex = treeDataItem.meta('index');
  });
```

and then you go like this:

```
  treeData.listen(anychart.enums.EventType.TREE_ITEM_MOVE, function(e) {
    /*
        Event e contains the following useful fields:
      e.type - Event type
      e.item - Moved item.
      e.target - Target data item that becomes a parent of the moved item.
        If is null, the parent is tree itself and moved item becomes root.
      e.targetIndex - Index of moved item in target item 
        (or in roots of tree if e.target is null)  
      e.source - Source data item, where the item moved from.
      e.sourceIndex - Old index of the moved item of the previous parent.
    */

    var treeDataItem = e.item;
    alert('Old absolute index: ' + absoluteSourceIndex + '\n' +
        'New absolute index: ' + treeDataItem.meta('index') + '\n' +
        'Old index in old parent tree data item: ' + e.sourceIndex + '\n' +
        'New index in new parent tree data item: ' + e.targetIndex);
  });
```

Here is a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mhm7hbsb/1/